# onMove() event doesn't fire in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

Code from [demo link](http://jsbin.com/ifuma#noedit) works on IE8 but not in IE9. What's the reason of this?

How to force it work on IE9?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Simple drag demo</title>
    <style>
#dragme {
  position:absolute;
  cursor:move;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:10px;
}
    </style>

<script>
function makeDraggable(element) {

  /* Simple drag implementation */
  element.onmousedown = function(event) {
    if(element.setCapture) { element.setCapture(); }

    document.onmousemove = function(event) {
      event = event || window.event;
      element.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
      element.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    };

    document.onmouseup = function() {
      if(element.releaseCapture) { element.releaseCapture(); }

      document.onmousemove = null;
    };
  };

  /* These 3 lines are helpful for the browser to not accidentally 
   * think the user is trying to "text select" the draggable object.
   * Unfortunately they also break draggability outside the window.
   */
  element.unselectable = "on";
  element.onselectstart = function(){return false};
  element.style.userSelect = element.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body onload="makeDraggable(document.getElementById('dragme'))">
    <div id="dragme">Drag me (outside window)</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesnt work how?  Provide some details please of what you expect it to do.

Comment: Block cann't be moved in IE9.

It uses some other events than onMove() but that events are not fired as well.

Can't give complete demo with onMove() sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's because IE can't retreive mouse X/Y position

More information:

- http://javascript.about.com/library/blmousepos.htm
- http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B14007C5C6A87256B4B0005BFA6
- http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html
- http://expsharing.blogspot.com/2008/08/following-javascript-help-we-get.html

Comment: How is the div moving for me in IE7-9 if it can't get mouse X/Y position :P

Comment: This demo is working in IE8 at least, so seems that problems described in your links aren't related to mine